# How did humans end up in space if Star Wars is set in the past?

Tags: star-wars

I’m of the understanding that the canon *Star Wars* movies are set in the relative past (18th and 19th century in our time). Yet looking up the biographies of characters like Padmé Amidala, Obi-Wan Kenobi, Anakin Skywalker etc their species is listed as ‘human’.

If they are indeed, human beings as you and I, how did they manage to end up in the far reaches of space hundreds of years ago, when we don’t have to technology to travel long distances in space even today?

Comment: I'm guessing here, but I think Lucas tried to find Rodians, but none came for the casting call...

Comment: it wa a long time ago far far away so 18th to 19th century is probably wrong

Comment: @Eumel Is the 18th century not a ‘long time ago’? ;)

Comment: Why can't humans develop independently in the galaxy far far away?

Comment: not long enough ;)

Comment: The best estimates for the beginning of unintended colonisation of Earth by human crash survivors is currently set at 2-5mya or earlier, so these events must have occurred much earlier than that.

Comment: @MartinBean You realize that there are people living now—lurking on this site for all we know—whose **grandfathers** were born in the 18th century? So, no, the 18th century is not a "long time ago".

Comment: @user14111 you realize that the 18th century is from 1700 till 1799 right? so it NOT possible to having a living grandparent born in the 18th century. But I Agree I wouldn't say it's that long ago

Comment: @user14111 Like Ivo Beckers says, the 18th century is 1700-1799, so if you _do_ know living people whose grandparents were born then, I’d love to meet them.

Comment: @MartinBean Look up the Wikipedia article on John Tyler (1790-1862), 10th president of the United States, and read about his two living grandchildren.

Comment: @IvoBeckers I didn't say "living grandparent". I said living person whose grandfather (long gone of course) was born before 1800. Please read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Tyler#Family_and_personal_life) and [this](http://www.stategazette.com/story/2022587.html) and [this](http://nymag.com/daily/intelligencer/2012/01/).

Comment: @user14111 yeah, the living grandparent was a mistake, but I actually didn't think it possible have a grandparent born in the 18th century. Learnt something new today :) Apology for that

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Humans in *Star Wars* are not the species *homo sapiens* that we find on Earth. And they also don't speak English. There is deliberately no connection between "a long time ago in a galaxy far far away" and any place or time that we know of. So the word that is translated into English as "human" is simply the word that they use to refer to the species in the *Star Wars* universe that *looks* like *homo sapiens*.